# My Tensorflow neural network is still pretty stupid, after much remedial education

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

I am fairly new at image classification and tensor flow and have been engaged in a little toy project for self-education. It is an image classification project that sorts photographs of cars into 16 different classes. The photographs are taken from the Kaggle Carvana competition, which had different goals and evaluated according to a different criteria.

What I am trying to do is find out if I can tell that an image of a car is taken with the car pointed directly at the camera, or at any one of 16 radial points around the vehicle. This should be a fairly straightforward image classification problem.

What I am doing in essence is to see the images into a neural network that does two relu feed-forwards, runs an AdamOptimizer (or others, no better) then scores them.
The problem I have been having is that the network never seems to learn-it always shows a loss of right around 2.80 (sometimes a little higher, sometimes a little lower) and never ever seems to wise up. The performance is never much better than right around random guessing. I have been tweaking, muttering, and staring for a long time. I fear I am losing my sanity.

The crucial code for the loss, training and evaluation operations is posted below. When I call this, the vital parameters are:

```
--target carvana --numclasses 16   --batch_size 64  --show True --learning_rate 0.01 --epochs 10 --scale 8.0 --hidden1_units 128 --hidden2_units 32
```

The complete code is at https://github.com/WascallyWabbit/estimator .

Thanks, 
Wabbit

```
(image_placeholder, label_placeholder) = target.get_graph_placeholders(img_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                                                       batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)

logits_op = target.inference(images_placeholder=image_placeholder,
                             hidden1_units=FLAGS.hidden1_units,
                             hidden2_units=FLAGS.hidden2_units)

loss_op = target.loss(logits=logits_op,
                      labels=label_placeholder)

train_op = target.training(learning_rate=FLAGS.learning_rate,
                           loss_op=loss_op)

evaluation_op = target.evaluation(logits=logits_op,
                                  labels=label_placeholder)

# blah, blah...
def get_graph_placeholders(self, img_shape=None, batch_size=10, num_classes=16):
    if img_shape == None:
        img_shape = self.img_shape

    pixel_num = ut.pixnum_from_img_shape(img_shape)

    images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, pixel_num), name='Images')
    labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(batch_size), name='Labels')

    return (images_placeholder, labels_placeholder)

def inference(self,
              images_placeholder,
              hidden1_units,
              hidden2_units,
              num_classes = 16,
              img_shape=None):

    if img_shape == None:
        img_shape = self.img_shape
    pixel_num = ut.pixnum_from_img_shape(img_shape)


    with tf.name_scope('inference'):
        #       with tf.name_scope('inference'):
        #       display_tensor = tf.reshape(tensor=images_placeholder, shape=[100,28,28,1])
        #      tf.summary.image(tensor=display_tensor, max_outputs=3,name="Carvana_images")
        display_tensor = tf.reshape(tensor=images_placeholder, shape=[64,img_shape[1],img_shape[0],1])
        tf.summary.image(tensor=display_tensor, max_outputs=320,name="Carvana_images")

        with tf.name_scope('hidden1'):
            weights1 = tf.Variable(
                tf.truncated_normal([pixel_num, hidden1_units],
                                          stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(float(pixel_num))),
                                          name='weights1')
            biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden1_units]),
                                 name='biases1')

            hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(images_placeholder, weights1) + biases1)
            tf.summary.histogram(name='weights1', values=weights1)
            tf.summary.histogram(name='biases1', values=biases1)


        with tf.name_scope('hidden2'):
            weights2 = tf.Variable(
                tf.truncated_normal([hidden1_units, hidden2_units],
                                          stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(hidden1_units))),
                                          name='weights2')
            biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden2_units]),
                                 name='biases2')

            hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden1, weights2) + biases2)
            tf.summary.histogram(name='weights2', values=weights2)
            tf.summary.histogram(name='biases2', values=biases2)

        with tf.name_scope('softmax_linear'):
            weights3 = tf.Variable(
                tf.truncated_normal([hidden2_units, num_classes],
                                          stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(hidden2_units))),
                name='weights3')
            biases3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_classes]),
                                 name='biases3')

            logits = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden2, weights3) + biases3)

            tf.summary.histogram(name='weights3', values=weights3)
            tf.summary.histogram(name='biases3', values=biases3)
            tf.summary.histogram(name='logits', values=logits)

        return logits

def loss(self,logits,labels):
    with tf.name_scope('loser'):
        labels=tf.to_int64(labels)
        cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            labels=labels, logits=logits, name='xentropy')

        rm = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
        tf.summary.scalar('xentropy_reduced_mean', rm)
        return rm

def evaluation(self, logits, labels):
    with tf.name_scope('evaluation'):
        correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits,labels,1,name='correct_evaluation')
    #    tf.summary.scalar('Evaluation', correct)
        rs = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct,tf.int32), name='Reduce_sum')
        tf.summary.scalar('Reduced sum', rs)
        return correct

def training(self, loss_op, learning_rate):
    with tf.name_scope('training'):
        tf.summary.scalar('Training loss_op', loss_op)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate, name='Adam_Optimizer')
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
        tf.summary.scalar('Training global_step', global_step)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op, global_step=global_step)
        return train_op

def init_weights(self,pixel_num,hidden1_units,hidden2_units,num_classes):
    w1 = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([pixel_num, hidden1_units],
                                  stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(pixel_num)),
                                  name='weights1')
    )

    w2 = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([hidden1_units, hidden2_units],
                                  stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(pixel_num)),
                                  name='weights2')
    )

    w3 = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([hidden2_units, num_classes],
                                  stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(hidden2_units)),
                                  name='weights3')
    )

    return (w1,w2,w3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your Network is too small. You are just using two hidden layers. The number of hidden units seem quite low. Try increasing your layer number and size.

Another idea is to use CNN layers for your classification problem, since they tend to be better for image classification then normal feed forward neural networks. 
Take a look at vgg 16 for example

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the other answer mentioning that such a small neural network will have a hard time with such a task, *especially* a fully-connected one, I think the major issue here is that you apply the `softmax` activation yourself to the output layer. This is not correct; when using the `cross_entropy_with_logits` functions, you need to pass the *pre-softmax* values. The softmax is done internally inside the cost function in a numerically stable way. Thus, you should remove `tf.nn.softmax` from the `logits` in the `inference` function.